# Azure Table Storage entity accessed via OData. PartitionKey and RowKey as Primary Keys

Tags: .net, wcf-data-services, visual-studio-2012, odata, azure-table-storage

I'm accessing a "Person" entity using Azure Table Storage via OData (WCF Data Service). I was having lots of issues for getting this to work. I was having this error:

Entity code:

```
public class Person : TableServiceEntity
{
public string Name { get; set; }
... etc
```

URI: 
    *http://127.0.0.1/DataService/PersonDataService.svc/Person*

Result:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'On data context type 'PersonDataServiceContext', there is
>   a top IQueryable property 'Person' whose element type is not an entity
>   type. Make sure that the IQueryable property is of entity type or
>   specify the IgnoreProperties attribute on the data context type to
>   ignore this property.'.

After a lot of troubleshooting, I found out through this [post](http://marcgravell.blogspot.ca/2008/12/astoria-and-linq-to-sql-getting-started.html) that in order to get around this error, I could add to my entity :

1) [DataServiceKey] attribute to add custom Keys (I need [DataServiceKey("PartitionKey", "RowKey")])

2) By looking for a "PersonID" property (This is the only one that works for me)

3) By looking for an "ID" property

No 1 is the only one that works for me. I had to add a "PersonID" column, like this:

Entity code:

```
public class Person : TableServiceEntity
{
public Guid PersonID { get; set; } //This is absolutely necessary to get around the aforementioned error
public string Name { get; set; }
... etc
```

I successfully get data via *http://127.0.0.1/DataService/PersonDataService.svc/Person* or by specifying the PersonID:
*http://127.0.0.1/DataService/PersonDataService.svc/Person(guid'e4a924d1-a564-45d7-9e3e-fe0396d08f8e')*

I would like to specify a custom Primary Key column, such as PartitionKey/RowKey (coming from TableServiceEntity), but using this code does not help:

```
[DataServiceKey("PartitionKey", "RowKey")]
public class Person : TableServiceEntity
{
public string Name { get; set; }
... etc
```

Is this a bug? 
Do I have to follow that convention for every entity that I have? Person => PersonID, Foo => FooID, etc.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, and Silverlight 5, .NET Framework 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [WCF Data Service and Azure Table Storage: How can I use PartitionKey / RowKey as primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376741/wcf-data-service-and-azure-table-storage-how-can-i-use-partitionkey-rowkey-as/)...

This appears to be a limitation of the Reflection Provider, and probably not an intended limitation. I'll file this as a bug internally, but here is a workaround until we get to a fix...

You can use the [new modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=VS.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier) to hide pass the desired values through/from the base class:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Services.Common;

namespace SO.OData
{
    [DataServiceKey("PartitionKey", "RowKey")]
    public class Question : TableServiceEntry
    {
        public new string PartitionKey
        {
            get { return base.PartitionKey; }
            set { base.PartitionKey = value; }
        }

        public new string RowKey
        {
            get { return base.RowKey; }
            set { base.RowKey = value; }
        }

        public string Text { get; set; }
        public User AskedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset AskedAt { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class TableServiceEntry
    {
        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
        public string RowKey { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample that is pretty close to what you are trying

[Windows Azure Walkthrough: Table Storage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2008/10/28/walkthrough-simple-table-storage.aspx)

[Understanding the Table Service Data Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179338.aspx)

Every entry much have a PartitionKey and a RowKey and the combination must be unique.  Based on the first link the rowkey can be string.empty.