# WCF Data Service and Azure Table Storage: How can I use PartitionKey / RowKey as primary keys

Tags: .net, wcf-data-services, visual-studio-2012, odata, azure-table-storage

Why does the following code of my entity "Person" generates an error in my WCF Data Service:

```
[System.Data.Services.Common.DataServiceKey("PartitionKey", "RowKey")]
public class Person : TableServiceEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    ... etc
```

Error:

> Request Error
>
> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'On data context type 'PersonDataServiceContext', there is
>   a top IQueryable property 'Person' whose element type is not an entity
>   type. Make sure that the IQueryable property is of entity type or
>   specify the IgnoreProperties attribute on the data context type to
>   ignore this property.'. See server logs for more details. The
>   exception stack trace is:
>
> at
>   System.Data.Services.Providers.ReflectionServiceProvider.PopulateMetadata(IDictionary`2
>   knownTypes, IDictionary`2 childTypes, IDictionary`2 entitySets) at
>   System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.LoadMetadata() at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateMetadataAndQueryProviders(IDataServiceMetadataProvider&
>   metadataProviderInstance, IDataServiceQueryProvider&
>   queryProviderInstance, BaseServiceProvider& builtInProvider, Object&
>   dataSourceInstance) at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider() at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest() at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream
>   messageBody) at SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object , Object[] ,
>   Object[] ) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

What am I doing wrong? 
If I add a property called PersonID, the error is gone, but I need to access my entity through the PartitionKey and RowKey, and the DataServiceKey decoration in the class is not doing anything.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, .NET Framework 4.0, Silverlight 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a limitation of the Reflection Provider, and probably not an intended limitation. I'll file this as a bug internally, but here is a workaround until we get to a fix...

You can use the [new modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=VS.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier) to hide pass the desired values through/from the base class:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Services.Common;

namespace SO.OData
{
    [DataServiceKey("PartitionKey", "RowKey")]
    public class Question : TableServiceEntry
    {
        public new string PartitionKey
        {
            get { return base.PartitionKey; }
            set { base.PartitionKey = value; }
        }

        public new string RowKey
        {
            get { return base.RowKey; }
            set { base.RowKey = value; }
        }

        public string Text { get; set; }
        public User AskedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset AskedAt { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class TableServiceEntry
    {
        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
        public string RowKey { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your answer. I just tried declaring the PartitionKey and RowKey with the new modifier just like you indicated, and still I get the error. Thank you for filing this as a bug. While it gets fixed, I'll be using <<My Class>>ID as primary key in all my entities. If there a way to track this bug, please let me know, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't have a way to expose the bug visibly, sorry. I'm interested in the fact that you still get the error - do you have a sanitized project you can send me with a repro?

Comment: Here you have a sanitized project showing the error:

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=D45129AD92C1E23C!163&authkey=!ANFOLVAYkvlUKa4

You can access the wcf data service using this link: http://127.0.0.1:8080/DataService/WcfDataService.svc/People
The entity is in \WebRole.Services\Entities\Person.cs. Let me know if you could download the project successfully. Thanks so much for your help Mark.

Comment: Hi Mark, could you replicate the error with the project I sent you?